# Hibernate does not refresh entity childs completely

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jpa, entitymanager

I use Hibernate 5.1.0.Final. My `GenericDAO` class main methods:

```
public T save(T entity) {
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}

public T find(Long entityId) {
    T e = (T) entityManager.find(type, entityId);
    entityManager.refresh(e);
    return e;
}
```

I have `Item` entity which contains `List<Image> images`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="item")
public class Item extends GenericEntity {

    @Column(name="title")
    String title;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "item", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    List<Image> images;

    @Version
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="version")
    Date version;

}


@Entity 
@Table(name="image")
public class Image extends GenericEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="item")
    Item item;

    @Column(name="image_name")
    String imageName;

}
```

First, I load `Item` with `genericDAO.find(id)` method - it contains up-to-date list of images. Then I load `Item` with the same ID in another REST method which removes old images and adds new ones, changes title. Later, if try to reload `Item` with `genericDAO.find(id)` in the first REST method, I get outdated images - they aren't selected again while `Item` title is retrieved correctly.

How to get completely refreshed entity with its childs from a database?

Comment: Are you sure that your update the `images` field  ?

Comment: Yes, the changes are visible if I query directly from the DB.

Comment: so you use a cache somewhere. do you use a level 2 cache with Hibernate ? Or any cache mechanisms in your application ?

Comment: My Hibernate properties contain:   properties.put("hibernate.cache.use.query_cache", "false");
properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "false"); Also I expect that entityManager.refresh(e); should get the newest data.

Comment: Indeed, it should. Do you use the same session for the two calls ?
if it is the same, the problem is there. You can check it with an session. evict() of the object

Comment: I use EntityManager instead of Session, it is reused for the two calls. It is provided from ThreadLocal<EntityManager>. I know that it may be problem but guessed that entityManager.refresh(e) will solve the issue. Now I get No row with the given identifier exists: [com.example.Image#484] when I try to entityManager.refresh(item) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of caching your `entityManagers` is correct since in the `request` scope but it has side-effects as you can notice. 
 
You use the level one cache of Hibernate.
Why don't use a distinct `entityManager` instance by transaction ?
It should not be expensive to instantiate a EntityManager by user request.

If you want to cache the entityManager, `entityManager.refres‌​h(e)` seems not enough since it doesn't seem to clear the level one cache. So, if you want to clear the first level cache, you should try to clear the `persistenceContext`. No guarantee but you can try : `entityManager.clear()`

Personally, I prefer the solution using a unique `entityManager` instance by transaction. It's cheap and a clear design.

Comment: entityManager.clear(); before injecting it to DAO solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1st/2nd level cache of Hibernate has nothing to do with visibility when there are simultaneous changes to DB. You need to look at isolation levels, `REPEATABLE_READ` is most common and should be source of your problems.

You could "lock" entity to prevent modifications:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Transactional
@Test
public void lock() {
    final Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
    final Book book = session.get(Book.class, 1L, LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
}
```

Depending on DB / Hibernate adapter it might resulted in `SELECT .... FOR UPDATE`.